# How to protect our code in react-native SDK?

Tags: react-native, sdk

We are developing a react-native SDK but are trying to protect part of the code. Can anyone suggest how it can be done ?

Library in npm is currently public but we need to protect at least pert of the code. Is there a way to distribute it as a binary code ?

Comment: What do you mean by protect the code? Like prevent reverse engineering? You could use an obfuscator, but that is futile against any serious reverse engineering.